# what is the difference between any[] and [] in typescript

Tags: typescript

So the first example here works,

```
protected createGroups(sortedItems: Array<TbpeItem>): any[] {
    let groups: any[] = [];
    return groups;

}
```

but the second one gives a typescript error:
    type any[] not assignable to type []

```
protected createGroups(sortedItems: Array<TbpeItem>): [] {
    let groups: any[] = [];
    return groups;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any[]` is an array where the item is of type `any`. `[]` is the empty tuple. Tuples are represented in typescript as arrays where the type of each position is known (ex `[boolean, number]` is a tuple where the first item is a `boolean` and the second is a `number`). When checking compatibility for tuples the size has to be the same, so this means nothing but `[]` is assignable to the empty tuple type. Read more about tuples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)